# Inserting into empty Excel tables with SQL, without losing data type property

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, vba

I'm running som VBA code with SQL to insert from one sheet to another. My problem is that when I use the `INSERT INTO` statement, I lose the data type property in empty tables.

This is the code I'm running:

```
Sub InsertTest()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fromFile As String
fromFile = "C:\some\file.xlsx"
Dim cnStr As String
cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & fromFile & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

Dim query As String

query = "INSERT INTO [TableTwo$](lastname, age) SELECT lastname, age FROM [TableOne$]"

rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified 
End Sub
```

Table one is where I get my data from:

[image]

Table two is where I insert data, here is how it looks after the code is executed:

[image]

I noticed that if TableTwo is populated with data of correct data types, the `INSERT INTO` statement also inserts data of correct data type. I don't know if it's excel who's doing this or if its ADODB. Do you know?

I've tried to alter the schema of the TableTwo. I've also tried the `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` functions, but I can't make it work:(

I know that I easily can fix data types by some simple VBA code, but in my mind that defeats some of the purpose of using SQL. I would really hate to iterate over my sheets and tables with VBA because it's incredibly much slower than SQL in my experience.

Another thing I noticed is that when I use SQL, the data in the formula line has a quotation mark (like this ') in the beginning of the word. But it doesn't in the cell. Why does it do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An `Excel` table column can contain mixed data types. There is no data type definition like for database fields. So `ADODB` is guessing what data type a column might be. But for this some data must already be there. Write at least one lastname and age in row 2 of `TableTwo` manually with a number in cell `B2` and the data type will be guessed as numeric.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for your answer. So you're positive that you can't brute force the correct data type? Why doesn't 'CAST()' or 'CONVERT()' work?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. `Cast` and `Convert` could only be applied in the `SELECT` part of your `SQL` statement. But that part is not the problem. The problem is that there are no field definitions for `Excel` tables. You wrote you've tried to alter the schema of the TableTwo. How? As far as I know there is not such a shema. So the data type can only be guessed. And without data `ADODB` guesses text data type. And because the `SELECT` part provides numeric data in `[age]` those data will be implicitly converted to text. Thats why the `'` in front of the values.

Comment: @AxelRichter `ALTER TABLE` doesn't work at all. So I think you're right. However I think it's a shame, because it forces me to code in a more "hacky" way by adding a dummy in the second row. I'm also a bit dissapointed because `SQL` is such a powerfull language, but it seems I can't take full advantage of it's strengths working with excel. 

Politics aside; thank you for your answer! :)